# Rebind ko.observables to template in Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Here is the setup that I have for template.html and script.js: I have a knockout component with a few knockout observables which are bound to a template for a popup. I have several components displayed on the page but they all use the same popup. The problem I have is that only the first component is bound to the popup and not the remaining ones, so changing the values only affect the first component. Here's a basic structure of the code:

```
ko.components.register('ko-component', {
  viewModel: function(params) {
    var variable = ko.observable(1);
  },
  template: { require: 'text!' + root + 'templates/template.html' }
});


<input type="text" data-bind="value: variable" placeholder="Enter variable here...">
```

The approach I want to take is to clear and re-bind the observables to the popup every time it pops up. I just cannot find the right syntax to do so. I've tried

```
ko.cleanNode(element);
```

but it does not work as apparently it is not part of the Knockout API.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: Can you post the code for your popup please. Also the code for how you create and display the popup. Thanks

Comment: The problem is that it is part of a larger system and it would be hard to replicate the whole thing in a fiddle. I am not familiar enough with Knockout to abstract it. I will try to make one but it'll take me a little while.

Comment: We can't answer your question if you can't provide us with a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Right I totally understand and like I said, I need to find the time to port the problem into a fiddle. I should have something to show tomorrow. Thank you for the help and patience :-)